# How to check if a column ends with either a or b in pandas

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I need to filter columns by the last character, testing against multiple characters.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("F:\\bridges.txt", names = ['IDENTIF','RIVER', 'LOCATION', 'ERECTED', 'PURPOSE', 'LENGTH', 'LANES', 
 'CLEAR-G', 'T-OR-D', 'MATERIAL', 'SPAN', 'REL-L', 'TYPE']) 

print(df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('N' or 'H' or 's') ])
```

Output:

```
Index(['LOCATION', 'SPAN'], dtype='object')
```

Here I am not getting all columns ending with either `N`, `H` or `s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Index.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) with a `tuple`, followed by Boolean indexing:

```
L = ['IDENTIF','RIVER', 'LOCATION', 'ERECTED', 'PURPOSE', 'LENGTH',
     'LANES', 'CLEAR-G', 'T-OR-D', 'MATERIAL', 'SPAN', 'REL-L', 'TYPE']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=L)

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith(tuple('HNS'))]

Index(['LOCATION', 'LENGTH', 'LANES', 'SPAN'], dtype='object')
```

The functionality mimics Python's built-in [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith), which allows you to supply a `tuple` to match against multiple items as alternative conditions.

Answer (score 2):

```
[col for col in df.columns if col[-1] in ['N', 'H', 'S']]
```

If I remember correctly, the `columns` attribute of a dataframe is not a series so you can't treat it as such. It's a list.

To clarify, the columns aren't technically lists. They are some variation of a special type of pandas Index. But for 99% of all intents and purposes they can be treated as lists. The point I'm trying to make clear is that they are `not` Series and thus don't have series methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_serial = df_copy.filter(regex = '(?:H|N|S)$' , axis=1)
print(df_serial)
```

Using regular expression we can do that